# Regex: simple Java Regex Question

Tags: java, regex

My XML is mal-formated for  tag. Specifically, I want every  tag that is not ended with  to be corrected. How do I match such pattern and using ReplaceAll to do that?

```
Pattern r = "<img.*?[^/]>" // sth like that?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon :)

No seriously, use a (X)HTML parser/cleanup API which can convert tagsoup (HTML) to XHTML. Under each [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) can do that in a single call:

```
new Tidy().parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Regex is simply not well suited for this job.

Comment: Thanks. But is it necessary to include an external library for this simple operation? I just want something simpler.

Comment: Simple operation? Why can't you code it yourself than? ;) It really isn't as simple as you seem to think.

Comment: Just add the jar to your classpath :)

Comment: Sorry I am developing for mobile apps so I need to minimize the usage of outcoming resources to ensure the performance. I don't see it necessary to add the jar at this moment. I'll see if someone else can come up with a better idea.

Comment: Well, then write/reinvent HTML parser/cleanup API yourself so that you don't need to include a JAR :)